# For Loop with BigIntegers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to generate ten large prime numbers. here is my code. I use small numbers to see if it's working.

```
    public static void primeGenerator(){
    BigInteger[] primeList = new BigInteger[10];
    BigInteger startLine = new BigInteger("1");
    int startPower = 1;
    BigInteger endLine = new BigInteger("10");
    int endPower = 2;
    int j = 0;
    for (BigInteger i = startLine.pow(startPower);
            i.compareTo(endLine.pow(endPower)) <= 0;
            i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {

        if(checkPrimeFermat(i) == true && j<10)
            primeList[j] = i;
            j++;
            continue;

    }

    System.out.print(primeList[3]);

}
```

the outputs:

```
primeList[0] = null primeList[1] = 2 primeList[2] = 3 primeList[3] = null
```

outputs I want to generate:

```
primeList[0] = 2 primeList[1] = 3 primeList[2] = 5 primeList[3] = 7
```

when the j comes the 4 code didn't check 5 and stop in here. How can I solve this problem? I tested checkPrimeFermat with junit it's working by the way.

Comment: The indentation of the if statement and the following couple of statements does not match their logic. `j++;` and `continue` are executed regardless of the checkPrimeFermat result.

Comment: You are missing braces in your if statement, so you are always incrementing j whether or not you store a value.

Comment: Looks like you're adding the values even if they aren't prime (and thus return null)

Comment: presence of `;` after `for`...absence of `{}` in if..

Comment: @GoldRoger `;` after `for`? Looks like a fine `for` statement in my opinion? The braces are missing in the `if` statement though :)

Comment: damn the indentation..my fault

Comment: looks like a python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll work:

```
public static void primeGenerator() {
        BigInteger[] primeList = new BigInteger[10];
        BigInteger startLine = new BigInteger("1");
        int startPower = 1;
        BigInteger endLine = new BigInteger("10");
        int endPower = 2;
        int j = 0;
        for (BigInteger i = startLine.pow(startPower); i.compareTo(endLine
                .pow(endPower)) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (checkPrimeFermat(i) == true && j < 10) {
                primeList[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(primeList));

    }
```